# App crashes with [BTAlert dismissAnimated:] unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, crash

In my App I see quite a few crashes with the stack trace below, in production.

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BTAlert dismissAnimated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f6d500'


Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2f57cf03 <redacted> + 130
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39d11ce7 _objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2f580837 -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2f57f12f <redacted> + 706
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2f4ce0d8 __CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5   CoreBluetooth                       0x2f2a508f -[BTDevicePicker dealloc] + 358
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39d20b6b <redacted> + 174
7   ExternalAccessory                   0x2fe93105 <redacted> + 56
8   ExternalAccessory                   0x2fe8b057 <redacted> + 898
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2f53ef39 <redacted> + 12
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2f4b2de9 __CFXNotificationPost + 1720
11  Foundation                          0x2fe9dcc5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
12  AppSupport                          0x32f7b3f7 -[CPDistributedNotificationCenter deliverNotification:userInfo:] + 62
13  AppSupport                          0x32f7b511 __CPDNDeliverNotification + 276
14  AppSupport                          0x32f7a8a3 <redacted> + 138
15  AppSupport                          0x32f6efb3 <redacted> + 146
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2f54783f <redacted> + 34
17  CoreFoundation                      0x2f5477db <redacted> + 346
18  CoreFoundation                      0x2f545fa7 <redacted> + 1406
19  CoreFoundation                      0x2f4b07a9 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
20  CoreFoundation                      0x2f4b058b _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21  GraphicsServices                    0x3441d6d3 _GSEventRunModal + 138
22  UIKit                               0x31e0f891 _UIApplicationMain + 1136
23  myapp                               0x00102647 __mh_execute_header + 30279
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x3a20fab7 <redacted> + 2
```

In my App I display a Bluetooth Picker dialog and I am guessing the crash happens when this dialog is closed. I have not been able to reproduce the crash myself. The code I use to the present the dialog is pretty straight forward.

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:
         [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS 'MyDeviceName'"] 
         completion:^(NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         DLog(@"Failed to search for blueetoh devices or user cancelled %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     } else {
         [self userDidConnectToBTFromInApp];
     }
}];
```

My guess is it has something to do with the BTPicker being deallocated before the dismiss method is called - but that is just a guess.

I have seen the crash on pretty much any type of iPhone or iPad, and on pretty much any version of iOS 6 and 7 (including 7.1).

If anybody has an idea why this is happening I will happy to hear about it:

Comment: What is `BTAlert`???? `dismissAnimated:` is a `BTDatePicker` method not a `BTAlert` method. There is your issue, `dismissAnimated:` is being called on `BTAlert` and not on `BTDatePicker`. If your not calling `BTAlert` which I don't believe you are, maybe raise it with the developer of the framework, which you can find in `ejazz`s answer.

Comment: From the headers it looks like `dismissAnimated:` is a method on the BTDevicePicker which is probably what you meant. My guess is that the method is invoked on the wrong object because the BTDevicePicker has already been deallocated. I believe I have seen this symptom before in similar cases. What I don't know is if there is anything I can do to prevent this.

Comment: Yes sorry was super tired when writing that.

Comment: Wanted to add that we are seeing the same crash intermittently in production only in our app, so far on iOS 8.2 and 8.3. Our app requires iOS 8 or later.

It comes in via HockeyApp every few days. No idea what we can do about it, as it seems like something on the iOS side unless we are breaking some rule while showing the picker.

The picker isn't the most robust, well-polished thing, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is an intermittent iOS issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with a delegate function, see https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/BTDevicePicker.h

It tries to call that function I think.

Other thing that might be possible is that you are using a method that is i.e. > iOs6, and the crash is happening on iOs 5. Can you check that?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my answer with a little more context. The API for displaying the picker is pretty closed and there is nothing much you can do except from what is in my example code as far as I know.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that it might have to be with running on different thread. In the demo app from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079) there is a warning in the `EADSessionController.h`: `// NOTE: EADSessionController is not threadsafe, calling methods from different threads will lead to unpredictable results`